# Recurrence relation proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $\alpha$  be a positive integer. Let $b_n$, $n=1, 2, 3 \ldots$ be the sequence given by the recurrence relation  $b_{n+2}=2\alpha^2b_{n+1}-\alpha^4 b_{n}$, $n=1, 2, 3 \ldots$ with initial conditions $b_1=5\alpha^2$, $b_2=9\alpha^4$. Prove that for all positive integers $\gamma$ and $j$, we have that $4\gamma+3$ is not equal to $b_j$.

What I have so far:

the characteristic equation is $r^2 - 2\alpha^2r + \alpha^4 = (r-\alpha^2)^2 = 0$ So $\alpha^2$ is a root with multiplicity 2. Therefore, the general solution to this relation is as follows

$b_n = (x_1 + x_2n)(\alpha^2)^n = (x_1 + x_2n)(\alpha^{2n})$

using the intitial conditions we get

$5α^2 = (x_1 + x_2(1))(\alpha^{2(1)}) = (x_1 + x_2)(\alpha^2)$

$5 = x1 + x2$

$9\alpha^4 = (x_1 + x_2(2))(\alpha^{2(2)}) = (x_1 + 2x_2)(\alpha^4)$

$9 = (x_1 + 2x_2) = (5 - x_2 + 2x_2) = 5 + x_2$

Therefore $x_2 = 4$ and $x_1 = 1$

The solution is $(1 + 4n)\alpha^{2n}$

From here I am not sure what to do. I was thinking I could show that $(1 + 4n)\alpha^{2n} \not \equiv 3 \text{ (mod 4)}$ and therefore $a_i \not = 4\gamma + 3$, but I have not made much progress. Any help on this one is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  it suffices to consider the recursion $\pmod 4$.  You only need to consider $4$ values of $\alpha$.  Or, actually, only $2$ values.

Comment: ok so $2\alpha^2 b_{n-1} - \alpha^4 b_{n-2} \equiv 2 \alpha^2 (1 + 4(n-1))\alpha^{2(n-1)} - \alpha^4(1 + 4(n-2))\alpha^{2(n-2)} \equiv 2 \alpha^{2n} (1 + 4(n-1)) - \alpha^{2n}(1 + 4(n-2))  \equiv 2\alpha^{2n} - \alpha^{2n} \equiv \alpha^{2n} (2 - 1) \equiv \alpha^{2n} \text{ mod 4}$.  how do I know that $ \alpha^{2n} \not \equiv 3 \text{ mod 4}$?

Comment: You're soooooooo close. Do you know that? $x^2 \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{4}$? If so, apply that directly to $ x = \alpha^n$.

Comment: That's all more work than you need.  As a warm up. suppose $\alpha $ is even.  Now prove (without any heavy calculating) that all the $b_n$ are divisible by $4$.  The odd case is slightly harder but not much.